# How to restart VOLD daemon or send it commands?

Tags: android, linux, daemon, android-source

This is the latest VOLD daemon from Android 4.3:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/vold/+/master

It uses a new unified `/fstab.<device>` configuration file. Once I've modified the file in the rootfs ramdisk, I need to restart VOLD or make it reload the configuration file. I can't seem to figure out the commands or any command line parameters it takes in order to do this.

Comment: How did you modify the file? Have you rooted your phone?

Comment: Yes. It's in the ramdisk from the kernel image though. Thus changes to it don't persist. That's why I need to reload VOLD somehow after modifying it.

Comment: Why not just kill it and let it restart again?

Comment: It creates directories for block devices and mounts them. It needs to be gracefuly reloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although vold is responsible for mounting removable media, asecs and obbs it actual has little to do with the device specific `fstab.<device>` file.

This is instead used by the init process to mount the system and data partitions. The init process defines a command "mount_all" which takes an `fstab.<device>` file as a parameter. For example of the Nexus4 (mako) the the init.mako.rc script (located in device/lge/mako in the aosp source) in the "on fs" section calls

mount_all ./fstab.mako

If you are working on an existing device you will need to modify the `fstab.<device>` file in the ramdisk image and reflash the boot partition. This makes it difficult to do this at runtime.

Comment: Was this the same when the file was /system/etc/vold.fstab in 4.2?

Comment: Yes. I mostly work on 4.2, and have only been just recently looking at 4.3.